How do I resize my Banana game's window?
I am trying to play the Banana game, but every time I open the game, then the window is super tiny in the top left corner of my screen and I can't click on anything. I can't resize it either.
This is how it looks:

And this is how tiny it is on my whole screen:


What can I do to get the game to resize or work correctly?

If you can click on the Settings button in the window, it allows you to change the game's resolution.
Else if launching from Steam, go to your game Properties by right clicking it, and in General you'll find "Launch Options". Here add the following parameters, and it should work as well: --screen-width 1280 --screen-height 720
If that is not possible, another way to modify it is to open your Registry Editor (type regedit in your Windows search bar), go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\OhYeah\Banana, and adjust the value of Screenmanager Resolution Height, Width, Window Height and Window Width to what you need (something like 1280 for width and 720 for height for instance).

I can't click on anything in the game. The Settings button doesn't work.

In that case I would advise going for any of the two other options which should definitely solve the issue for you.
